# Use Redux Toolkit just in part of project

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I start to work with a react project, to create new funtionalities.
The project until now is created with react pure.
I want to implement redux toolkit for the new part of the app.(to create forms, get data from data base, etc).
Do you think that is it possible combine the old part with 'pure' with the new components with RTK?

Thanks.

Comment: React isn't Redux - but if your project already has React then you already have Redux implemented for you, so what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Yes, i know that. But until now, any component, state and function is managed with redux. (The other developer didn't know redux). Kmow i  continue with the project and want use RTK. For your answer understand that is possible, start with RTK for the new components, state and functions.

Comment: Redux does not manage component state: your own code does that, Redux just enforces a unidirectional flow of data. Redux has no concept of a "component" at all, in fact.

Comment: Yes, sorry for my explanations. I know redux manage states of variables. I want to know if i can start to use RTK in a project where never Redux or RTK was used.

Comment: Yes, you can - that's why I like the RTK library: because you can add it to existing, non-React, non-Redux projects - whereas adding React to an existing project is haaaard.

Comment: Yes it is haaaard, i know, in this case, react is implemented from the beginning so just is start to use RTK. Thanks for your answers.